# Does changing the contents of index.html require restart of IIS Site?

Tags: html, css, iis, content-management-system

I am currently working on a site which is built in using a Custom Designed CMS (there are files with `.asp` extension). This site is really old and seems like running on `IIS Server`, which I don't have the access. User asked me to add few items. I made changes to `index.html` file and uploaded to the server, however, the changes don't seem to take in affect.

So my question to Pros, is, do i have to restart the `IIS` instance? I tried to change the `index.html` existing content such as Search Bar's placeholder text from **S**earch to **s**earch, uploaded the page and nothing happened. Also added new `p` tags and no luck.

I have never dealt with `IIS` site. Any suggestions? One thing for sure I can see is that the Home Page in Custom backend is pointing to the `index.html` file (which I am altering).

Comment: There are caches (browser, proxy, IIS output cache for example), so "the changes don't seem to take in affect" can be normal. If you want your changes to show immediately after editing, then learn each of the caching mechanisms and fight against them.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. I does require a reload/refresh at the client-side though.

-Tango

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have reloaded the page on web browser and even tried it in `Private Window`. Does not work.

Comment: Are you sure that index.html is actually generating the home page you are looking at? Since you mention a .asp app, it might be dynamically generating what you are seeing and skipping the index.html. Shift FT should force you to load a fresh page and push comes to shove, do IISRESET on the server and see if the edited page loads.

Comment: *Shift F5 - mobile app won't let me edit my comment :-/